# can conserved currents be spacelike?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, field-theory

Given a conserved current $J_\mu$ in flat space, $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$ on some set of equations of motions, can it be taken spacelike at least in some finite region of space, or there exist some physical (e.g. causal) obstruction to build such a configuration?

(As a tentative **extra** physical input that one could require, for example, is  that a global healthy charge can be constructed out of $J^\mu$, part of the question being the definition of `healthy')

**Extra edit**:
Let me add one comment that motivates (it is not even an argument) where this question comes from. It comes from the intuition that for localized weakly interacting particles I should be able somehow to think of conserved currents as of 4-vectors associated to their motions, that is something like $J^\mu \propto v^\mu$ where $v^\mu$ is the 4-velocity. In a sense the charge contained inside a given box changes because of the net flux of particles entering/leaving the box. Therefore, following this intuition I know that $v^\mu$ is timelike (or lightlike) with $v^0>0$, and hence any sum particles of this sort of particles would still produce a non-spacelike current, at least as long as the system is not strongly coupled. I am interested in proving such statement above as suggested by this intuition, either true or wrong.

Comment: A cloud of relativistic dust, by dint of its timelike four velocity, has a timelike current. Could you be more explicit in the type of object you are visualizing and the type of rest frames you are seeking, or seeking protection from?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't have a specific system in mind, otherwise I think I could just check how the current behaves. My question is instead about general principles, and it comes from the desire  to understand whether non-spacelike conserved currents are the norm, perhaps because of causality and positivity of energy. I will edit the answer to add where my intuition about this possible fact comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many simple examples. For example, for a system of positively charged particles moving one way and an equal density of negatively charged particles moving the opposite way, the current is purely spatial.

The only reason you might be confused about this point is if you imagined all particles always had to have the same velocity or same charge, but that’s very far from true.

Comment: yes, absolutely. Sorry for the dumb question then. Any electric current on neutral wires etc are examples.  I was confused also because I was thinking about fluids and trying to imagine $\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$ as some transport equation for a fluid. But $T^{\mu\nu}$ is different than $J^\mu$, as the former admits only positive density while the latter may have $J^0=0$ as you said. Ok, perhaps I should remove the question...